# Get text from SharePoint column variable - enhanced rich text format

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

How do I get just the "Description" text without all the formatting tags?  It is an enhanced rich text column, is there a way for me to keep it that way and get the text when I call for it?  I tried using Get Items and it is behaving the same way. I also tried odata=nometadata. thanks for any help!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what rich text field works in SharePoint online. The value in this field would be wrapped with html tag.

Here are two options for you:

1. Change the field to Plain text.
2. As  @teylyn said, use the action HTML to Text to convert the value.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

HTML tags in an enhanced rich text field is not metadata. By definition, the tags are part of the field contents.

There is an action called **HTML to Text** that you can use to convert a rich text field to plain text.  Depending on what all was included in the field, the readability of the result may suffer, though.